# PHP form handling with Bootstrap

Tags: php, forms, twitter-bootstrap, post

I have a general question about submitting a form via PHP.

Right now everything works fine, but I think I need an update on how to submit forms nowadays - it seems that I'm stuck in the year 2000 :)

I have a `backend.php` where I can do some rudimentary (`MySQL`) db changes. The form inputs are being sent to an `action.php` where all the queries are stored and executed.

My update process started with translating all the `MySQL` stuff to PDO and for easy template handling, I'm now using bootstrap too. I'd like to continue and get rid of this `action.php` redirection-thing that annoys me every time I have to change something.

**Would it be possible to have my `action.php` result load in a bootstrap modal (on backend.php) without?**

If you can give me some keywords I can search after, I'd be already happy :)

[backend.php overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CHf70.png)
[action.php result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0AKt.png)

Comment: ajax method is the keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Shehary, I could find something and the following code works like a charm - I even got it to work in a bootstrap modal!:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('submit', '#addimage', function(){
        var data = $(this).serialize();

        $.ajax({
            type : 'POST',
            url  : '../php/action.php',
            data : data,
            success :  function(data){
                $('#modal .modal-body').html(data);
                $('#modal').modal('show');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```